# Getting Null Pointer Exception on method getIntent().getCategories()

Tags: java, android

The following code is causing Getting Null Pointer Exception on method 'boolean java.util.Set.contains(java.lang.Object)' Null Pointer Exception. I suspect

> getIntent().getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)

is causing the problem.

Some of the users are reporting it's crashing when they're opening app from **Home Screen**. But It doesn't crash while opening from Playstore **Open** Button

Couldn't reproduce the issue on any of my devices but getting tons of crashes on Crashlytics. Any Idea what's happening?

```
private boolean hasPendingIntent() {
        return getIntent() != null && getIntent().getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && getIntent().getData() != null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This code block is not null safe. Because, before checking a set is null or not null, you are trying to fetch data from it.

It is not necessarily an intent must have one or more categories according to this statemment. For more follow the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#CategoryTest).

> An intent with no categories always passes this test, regardless of what categories are declared in the filter.

You need to check, Is getIntent().getCategories() null or not null first? After that, you should check, is it contains `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`.

```
getIntent()  != null && 
getIntent().getCategories() != null && getIntent().getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && 
getIntent().getData()
```

Comment: If get category is not null, is it possible that getCategories can be null?? Because all intent has category right?

Comment: I have updated the answer, maybe it can answer your query.

Comment: Android automatically applies the CATEGORY_DEFAULT category to all implicit intents passed to startActivity() and startActivityForResult().

so, if getIntent() is not Null, then getIntent().getCategories() should also be not null.

Comment: Yes, this is true but you should not rely on it all time. There will be many scenarios where any teammate may override default properties or configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You should check for null categories in getIntent().getCategories();
e.g: if(getIntent() != null && getIntenger().getCategories() !=null) {}

This will workaround the nullpointer. You may need to verify for empty categories list to preserve the current logic.

Answer (score 0):

add null point check before use, try to change the code below:

```
    private boolean hasPendingIntent() {
        boolean b = false;
        if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getCategories() != null && getIntent().getData() != null) {
            b = getIntent().getCategories().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        }
        return b;
    }
```